# Git LFS skipped files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I'm actually working on moving my larges files to Git LFS. I have successfully pushed a set of files.

In a previous commit but I have created a new one with just one files and when I using `git lfs push` command I obtain this output:

```
Git LFS: (0 of 0 files, 1 skipped) 0 B / 6.53 KB
```

Hence, my file was skipped. Why?

Comment: I'm getting this issue as well with artifactory, and I haven't seen a support response on the net so far. Other threads: [JFrog Forums](http://forums.jfrog.org/Git-LFS-files-not-getting-pushed-tt7581041.html), [SourceTree support](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/43345324/sourcetree-and-git-lfs-with-jfrogs-artifactory)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been back-and-forth with JFrog support, and some key info for the issue has been provided:

> ...it looks like you may have Anonymous Access enabled. If this is the case, then you are indeed running into [this bug](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-11955) which is scheduled to be released by Q1 of this year in Artifactory 5.0.So far, the only workarounds from Artifactory’s end are to disable anonymous access completely or to have the git credentials stored in your git config file. For the latter solution, this will need to be done per user and repository, which may not be ideal depending on the amount of users and repos that use GitLFS. You can write to the config manually or temporarily disable anonymous access so that when a 401 is returned, LFS automatically writes to the config file.

Let me know if this needs more clarification, and I can add some more detailed steps to debug and solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In fact this turned out to be the error @Tzrlk described
but this gives more information to diagnose for the end user.

```
trace git-lfs: HTTP: {
  "objects" : [ {
    "oid" : "d3e64a74919373d6d4d1d36bd717206584cb64cbb0532dfce3bc2081cba6817b",
    "size" : -1
  } ]
}
```

when running

> GIT_TRACE=1 git push

This is the response from the server.

this is mentioned in issues such as 
https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1364

it seem to suggest that the response is invalid.

This is a bug as described by @Tzrlk in his answer.